# I followed the google dev guide, however I keep getting a runtime error saying I did not correctly initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: java, android-studio, initialization, admob, runtimeexception

I'm trying to set up a banner ad at the bottom of my MainActivity. What am I doing wrong?

I have these in my AndroidManifest folder...

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ca-app-pub-8816120484641057~1397274829]"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />
```

And in my app gradle…

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:17.0.0'
```

google() is in my project gradle…

I initialized the ad...

```
 private AdView mAdView;

 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8816120484641057~1397274829");

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    // TODO: Add adView to your view hierarchy.

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);\
```

Here is my xml...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lstNotes"
    ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.913" />
```

The error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.venturaapps.smartnotes, PID: 31613
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here: **************** to add a valid  *
* App ID inside the AndroidManifest. Google Ad Manager publishers should     *
* follow instructions here: **************** .                           *
*****************************************************************************
```

Comment: Kindly remove the square brackets from the app Id in manifest file

Comment: It doesn't affect anything

Comment: if you just want to use Google Admob then simply remove AdManager from your manifest file. Remove this <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />